# Can't import Wavemaker .war file into Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, wavemaker

I have created a .war file (created under Tomcat 7) using the Wavemaker Studio. I have tried to deploy this .war file to a different Tomcat server. When I log into the Manager area (on the target system), and try to run it, I get a blank page. Is there any way for this to be done? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same issue and found out that the war name was the reason. It was formed with characters the system did not like such as ")(... 
Removing these characters did the trick for me. 
I am using Tomact8.

I've been using the community edition 6.7.0 which pretty stable and it runs well providing you update a couple of .jar files to the up-to-date version (wsdl for instance). Other than that the major issue is to find a decent documentation since the Wavemaker company does not give access to the dev.wavemaker.com site (wiki, forum and documentation of previous releases) and that's too bad...